# haskell show with function application

Tags: haskell, show

this line of code in Haskell produces an error on compilation:

```
lineStat :: String -> [String]
lineStat xs =  zipWith (\n line -> show n ++ " " ++ show $ length line) [1..] $ lines xs
```

Error:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int -> String` with actual type `[Char]`
    The first argument of ($) takes one argument,but its type `[Char]` has none

However this line of code works:

```
lineStat xs =  zipWith (\n line -> show n ++ " " ++ show (length line)) [1..] $ lines xs
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a precedence issue.

```
show n ++ " " ++ show $ length line
```

means

```
(show n ++ " " ++ show) (length line)
```

which makes no sense since `show` is not a string. It does not mean

```
show n ++ " " ++ (show (length line))
```

To get the wanted one, you need parentheses. Use one of these:

```
zipWith (\n line -> show n ++ " " ++ show (length line)) [1..] $ lines xs
-- or
zipWith (\n line -> show n ++ " " ++ (show $ length line)) [1..] $ lines xs
```

I'd prefer the former since it's simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem boils down to:

```
*Main> let line = "abc"
*Main> " " ++ show (length line)
" 3"
*Main> " " ++ show $length line
<interactive>:9:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> t’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
```

The root cause for this is that `$` has lower precedence than `++`:

```
*Main> :info (++)
...
infixr 5 ++
*Main> :info ($)
...
infixr 0 $
```

as defined in the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-820004.4.2)

Therefore, you need parentheses around `show $ length line`.